# Issue with balanceOf method call in bsc testnet

Tags: solidity

I am getting one weird issue when calling BEP20 standard method- balanceOf(address) for any address.
My contract is a BEP20 token, and it has all the standard functionalities of BEP20 protocols.

When I am calling the `balanceOf` method in bsc testnet, I am getting below error:

```
[ balanceOf method Response ]
    uint256 :  Error: Wrong response id "0" (expected: "5") in {"jsonrpc":"2.0"
  "id":5
  "method":"eth_call"
  "params":[{"from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  "data":"0x70a0823100000000000000000000000006125e1457f833e29d5aebaacdf8eed8a6febaee"
  "to":"0xb578afcda60b70d0572194a79b34679daaabb144"}
  "latest"]}
```

Testnet url: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xB578AFcDa60b70D0572194A79b34679dAAaBB144#readContract

The same method is working perfectly fine in mainnet.

Can someone please look into this, and share your views.

Comment: I have checked and I can successfully call balanceOf on your contract.

I think it's more an issue in your web3 code, could you please share it ?

Comment: yeah, it was related to my code. sorted now, thanks anyways!

Comment: I meet the same error because I use wrong rpc url!

Comment: just to add, this is working fine through web3 code. But if I got to the above testnet url, and exectute the balanceOf method- I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestion why is this happening?